# Combining a PHP loop with a random image (javascript) code

Tags: javascript, php, image, foreach

Hi I currently have a php foreach loop to display songs.

Now I want in the "image div" a different image every time the loop runs (so 1.jpg for first song, 2.jpg for second song, 3.jpg for third song,...)

My question is: how do I accomplish this easily with javascript or html?
(note: putting the images in the database is not an option)

btw: ignore the ????? in the code, it's where I want the images code to be.

```
<?php foreach($results as $row): ?>
    <div id="titlefirst">
        <h2><?php echo $row->titel ?></h2>
    </div>
    <div id="song">
        <iframe width="100%" height="150" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?
        &url=<?php echo $row->teaser ?>&amp;color=color=0066cc&amp&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_artwork=false"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="image">
        ??????
    </div>
    <div id="infom">
        <p>Componist: <?php echo $row->componist ?><br/>
        Tekstschrijver: <?php echo $row->tekstschrijver ?><br/>
        Taal: <?php echo $row->taal ?><br/>
        Thema: <?php echo $row->thema ?></p>

    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the iterator `$i` (starts at 0 and increments)

```
<?php foreach($results as $i => $row): ?>
```

Use it to form the image src

```
<img src="/url/to/images/<?php echo $i+1; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $row->titel ?>" />
```

Giving

```
<?php foreach($results as $i => $row): ?>
    <div id="titlefirst">
        <h2><?php echo $row->titel ?></h2>
    </div>
    <div id="song">
        <iframe width="100%" height="150" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?
        &url=<?php echo $row->teaser ?>&amp;color=color=0066cc&amp&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_artwork=false"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="image">
        <img src="/url/to/images/<?php echo $i+1; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $row->titel ?>" />
    </div>
    <div id="infom">
        <p>Componist: <?php echo $row->componist ?><br/>
        Tekstschrijver: <?php echo $row->tekstschrijver ?><br/>
        Taal: <?php echo $row->taal ?><br/>
        Thema: <?php echo $row->thema ?></p>

    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I fix the "undefined variable:i" error here?

Comment: There should be no undefined variable notice. Did you change the foreach line or just skip to the img?

Comment: yes my bad I forgot, thanks it works now! Honestly thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$count = 1;
foreach($results as $row){ ?>
            <div id="titlefirst">
                <h2><?php echo $row->titel ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div id="song">
                <iframe width="100%" height="150" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?
                &url=<?php echo $row->teaser ?>&amp;color=color=0066cc&amp&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_artwork=false"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="image">
                <img src="images/<?php echo $count; ?>.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div id="infom">
                <p>Componist: <?php echo $row->componist ?><br/>
                Tekstschrijver: <?php echo $row->tekstschrijver ?><br/>
                Taal: <?php echo $row->taal ?><br/>
                Thema: <?php echo $row->thema ?></p>

            </div>
            <?php 
$count++;
} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this code results in an undefined variable error though :/

Comment: Which one is undefined? `$count`?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is an error, I think OP is ignoring all but the `<img>` line in the given answers. You shouldn't set and continuously update $count when the foreach loop can use the implied keys of the array.

Comment: @MatthiasVerhoeven actually read the answers, don't just skip to the only bit you think has changed

Comment: Yes, my bad I'm sorry. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes... But we don't know whether it is an associative array or a regular array... So I wouldn't rely on the keys...